# Why sometimes javascript did'nt work? (i've use Ci)

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, codeigniter

I've use a long javascript code. When i first try it, it loads perfectly but when I continues used the system, some of the javascript functions didn't load anymore.

**Example:**

I have a dropdown list of members that will automatically popup a message if he/she has an unpaid debt to the other database.

Some of the members works perfectly, while the other names are not, which is they have the same value. I've observe also that sometimes when i choose a name it functions well but when i refresh and choose the same name it didn't function again. The sequel is (function,not function,function and not function again).

Do you have any idea what's happening of this? Or do you encountered like this? or is it on my codes that are wrong?

It would be helpful guys if you could help me.

This is is my view **transactions.php**

```
<div class="form-group" id="member_form">
                        <label for="member">Member</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="member" name="member" value="" required>
                            <option selected="" value="">--select--</option>
                            <?php foreach ($members as $row): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row->mem_id ?>"><?php echo ucwords($row->mem_fname.' '.$row->mem_lname) ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger" id="member_err"></p>


                        <span id="select" name="select" style="color: red;"> </span>

                        <div id="select">
                           <p class="help-block text-danger" style="color: red;" name="message" id="message"><span id="select_member" name="select_member"> </span></p> 

                           <p id="select_member" name="select_member"> </p> 

                            </div>

                    </div>

<script>
$('#member').on('change',function(){
    $.post('<?php echo base_url("loadscontroller/getdataload")?>',
        {
            member:$(this).val()
        }).done(function(res)
        {
        $('#select_member').text(res);
    });
});

$('#member').on('change',function(){
    $.post('<?php echo base_url("loadscontroller/getdataloadtwo")?>',
        {
            member:$(this).val()
        }).done(function(res)
        {
        $('#select').text(res);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my controller **loadscontroller.php**

```
    function getdataload(){

    $this->db->where('member',$this->input->post('member'));
    $result = $this->db->get('loading_service')->row()->status;


    $this->db->select_sum('total');
    $this->db->from('loading_service');
    $this->db->where('member',$this->input->post('member'));
    $this->db->where('status','unpaid');
    //$result2 = $this->db->get('loading_service')->row()->total;
    $query = $this->db->get(); 

    $result2 = $query->result();


    //var_dump($result2);

    if($result == 'unpaid')
    {

        foreach ($query->result() as $q) 
        {
            echo $q->total;
        }

    }

    else{
        echo "";
    }

}


function getdataloadtwo(){
    $this->db->where('member',$this->input->post('member'));
    $result = $this->db->get('loading_service')->row()->status;


    $this->db->select_sum('total');
    $this->db->from('loading_service');
    $this->db->where('member',$this->input->post('member'));
    $this->db->where('status','unpaid');
    //$result2 = $this->db->get('loading_service')->row()->total;
    $query = $this->db->get(); 

    $result2 = $query->result();


    //var_dump($result2);

    if($result == 'unpaid')
    {
        echo 'Have unpaid debt in Load. Total is: ';


    }

    else{
        echo "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Showing us some code would be useful please.

Comment: *"or is it on my codes that are wrong?"* - Well you didn't show your code, but yes, it is your code that is wrong.

Comment: okay i'll update my question. ^^

Comment: I've already upated my question ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can try debugging your website with Firefox Firebug, maybe any other tools available, it can shows the which request is the problem,

also you should remember, some server use linux, so everything on it is case-sensitive, every small typo can make you in trouble

Comment: i'm using chrome browser  :)..hmm...okay ^^

Comment: i've tested this but it's the same.

Comment: try using ajax,
are you sure your controller loadscontroller.php, have you try call it for the sequel manually?

Comment: i'm not really familiar with the ajax...hmm...what sequel do you mean @keronconk ?

Comment: you say the first access is success, but the next access is failed (function,not function,function and not function again)
have you tried controller loadscontroller.php manually before access it via javascript?

Comment: ahh okay sorry for that i thought you're talking about something...hmm..no, I haven't use it manually, i made it with the javascript at the first place.